# Sump Drainage Options

Tags: drainage, sump-pump, sump

I seem to have an overactive sump. Last year there was an empty lot next to my house. My builder raised my sump because it was running almost constantly. This year I installed sod and a small sump drainage area. There are two weeping tiles and a perferated tube connecting them (photos linked below).

There has been no rain, no watering but the drainage area remains full. I moved my sump hose to a back corner of my yard and now my neighbors yard and my sump drainage area are flooded. My sump is not running all the time.

The way I see it is I have two options.

1. Raise the sump again.
2. Extended my sump hose another 80 feet and drain it onto the street. Along my driveway I have 2 feet of black granite trim then grass. If I extend the hose I plan to dig up a small line of granite, place the hose in this dug out then every 6 to 8 inches drill/cut holes into the hose to make it perferated.

I am not sure which path to take. At this point I have given up on the sump drainage area as extending this will cost more than I am willing to pay at this time. I'm hoping someone can give me a better idea of how to proceed.

Thanks in advance!
[photos](https://photos.app.goo.gl/GXWfhuP5Njjexk2b9)

Comment: The description indicates the water table in your area is constantly high, are you near a lake or any water resources? Keep raising the sump pit might hurt the structure it is meant to protect, such as the basement. Do you have a stormwater line nearby, a ditch, or a creek, those are ideal recipients of your groundwater.

Comment: There is a man made lake a block away. Our cities floodway is also near by. I'm thinking more and more of extending my sump hose and just draining close to the street. Assuming that's not illegal

Comment: That's the thing you need to find out from the city or town hall before getting fined.

Comment: My neighbor has a burried hose that ends 5 feet before the street. I see it pouring out all the time. Makes me feel better because I think he would have looked it up.

Comment: Pray for him :) Seriously, you can add a gravel drainage ditch from the end of the hose to the street, so no water will stay in your yard, and not to wash top soil away.

Comment: Reading the RM bylaws it seems any "land drainage" is fair game to release into the "land drainage system". Sump water is considered "land drainage". So it seems good!

Comment: Good for you, and wish everything goes well.

Comment: Where is the sump pump discharging now?   If your backyard is flooded and the pump is not running, then the pump is too high, why would you want to raise it?  You would want to lower it to just above the water table.  The discharge hose should not be perforated, A perforated 'discharge' hose is a leak that is returning the water back into the soil.  You would have performated drain pipes/hoses that leads to your sump pump.

Comment: My original idea that I was writing up was to move the sump pump to the area where the water is collecting at the lower corner.  but I see in your last paragraph you are stating that this is not an option because of cost (I assume the cost of an electrician to move the electrical outlet vs DIY. )  if this is correct, I can write up a solution that allows the sump pump to remain where it is.